# Can I check results in the middle of a test in jmeter using a separate thread?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

I have a test in jmeter which takes about 15 minutes to complete. The process generates a lot of log entries and I would like to use a separate thread to poll this file for results every minute. Can someone tell me if this can be achieved in jmeter, and how I would implement it if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "poll". There are multiple options:

1. Manual

   - Launch a separate JMeter instance in GUI mode
   - Add a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice to the Test Plan
   - Using "Browse" button open the results file
2. Automated

   - Make sure "Run test groups consecutively" box is **unchecked** in [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
   - Add an additional [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with one thread and duration of 900 seconds (15 minutes)
   - Add a [Constant Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) and use `60000` as "Thread Delay"
   - Add a relevant sampler to do the "poll"
3. Using 3-rd party tool

   - You can run your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) framework, it displays interim results and statistics during test run directly in command-line. There is also an option to see charts in browser.

     [image: Taurus]

Comment: Thank you for that! Do you know if there is a way I can add a thread group within one that already exists? For example, if I only want to start checking the file after a certain point in the test?

Comment: JMeter doesn't support nested thread groups, you can delay 2nd thread group or use a plugin like http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/

Comment: Can I only delay the second thread with a timer, or can I use some condition based on the first thread? So I can have it starting when the first thread gets to a specific point